# Llamar a Provider usando Riverpod ()

Tags: flutter

Hola buenos días estimados.
Estoy creando una app para tener sincronizados los datos cuando tenga conexión a internet o cuando no consumir la base de datos local de Isar.

Lo primero que hago es que mando la pantalla del login y obtengo el estatus de la conexión a internet, después lo que quiero hacer pero no puedo es que al darle click al boton entrar llamar al provider de Riverpod y si si hay conexión que sincroniza los datos de la base de datos de Isar, de lo contrario que obtenga los que ya se tiene en Isar, pero no logro llamarlo.
Les comparto el código de lo que tengo hasta ahora.

Espero que me puedan orientar un poco, apenas estoy con el tema de Riverpod.

Se los agradesco.

Saludos!

> Código del Login (intento llamar a Riverpod al dar click al boton de Entrar y pasarle el estado de la conexión).

```
ValueNotifier<bool> isDeviceConnected = ValueNotifier(false);

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String name = 'login_screen';

  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  late StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> subscription;
  @override
  void initState() {
    IsarHelper.instance.init();
    super.initState();
    subscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) async {
      isDeviceConnected.value = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
      log("Internet status ====== $isDeviceConnected");
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _FormLogin();
  }
}

class _FormLogin extends ConsumerWidget {
  final ApiService api = ApiService();

  final _formLoginKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _user = '';
  String _password = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final colors = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;

    final bool statusConnection = ref.watch(statusConnectionProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Form(
            key: _formLoginKey,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(height: 50),
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/logo_ts_blue.png",
                    height: 130,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 25),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    // obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                        ),
                        fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: 'Usuario',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500])),
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose(
                      [
                        FormBuilderValidators.required(
                            errorText: 'Ingresa tu usuario'),
                        FormBuilderValidators.minLength(1),
                      ],
                    ),
                    // validator: (value) =>
                    //     Validation().validateUsername(value.toString()),
                    onChanged: (value) => _user = value.toString(),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    // obscureText: true,

                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                        ),
                        fillColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: 'Contraseña',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500])),
                    // validator: (value) =>
                    //     Validation().validatePassword(value.toString()),
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                    validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose(
                      [
                        FormBuilderValidators.required(
                            errorText: 'Ingresa tu contraseña'),
                        FormBuilderValidators.minLength(1),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) => _password = value.toString(),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Text(
                          '¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 25),
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text('Entrar'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // ---- AQUI ES DONDE INTENTO LLAMAR A RIVERPOD Y PASARLE EL ESTADO DE LA CONEXION A INTERNET

                      // ref.read(statusConnectionProvider.notifier).state =
                      //     isDeviceConnected.value;

                      if (statusConnection == true) {
                        print('conectado');
                      } else {
                        print('desconectado');
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 50),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Validation {
  //validar usuario
  String? validateUsername(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Ingresa tu usuario';
    } else if (value.length <= 4) {
      return 'Usuario muy corto';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  //validar contraseña
  String? validatePassword(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Ingresa tu contraseña';
    } else if (value.length <= 2) {
      return 'Contraseña muy corta';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

> Provider de Riverpod (obtengo estatus de la conexión y sincronizo
> datos).

```
final statusConnectionProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);

class ConnectionUsuarioNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  

  bool isLoading = false;
  List<Usuario> _usuarioList = [];
  List<Usuario> get inventoryList => _usuarioList;
  List<Usuario> deletedUsuarios = [];

  bool isSynced = true;

  void startLoading() {
    print('ENTRA A CARGAR');
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void stopLoading() {
    print('ENTRA A DESCARGAR');
    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

//===================================
//
//    ###    ####    ####
//   ## ##   ##  ##  ##  ##
//  ##   ##  ##  ##  ##  ##
//  #######  ##  ##  ##  ##
//  ##   ##  ####    ####
//
//===================================

  void addInventory(Usuario usuario) async {
    print('ENTRA A AGREGAR');
    usuario.isSynced = isDeviceConnected.value;
    int id = await IsarHelper.instance.insertOne(usuario);
    usuario.id = id;
    _usuarioList.add(usuario);
    if (isDeviceConnected.value) {
      // _cloudFirestoreHelper.addMedicine(usuario.toJson());
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

//===========================================================
//
//  ##   ##  #####   ####      ###    ######  #####
//  ##   ##  ##  ##  ##  ##   ## ##     ##    ##
//  ##   ##  #####   ##  ##  ##   ##    ##    #####
//  ##   ##  ##      ##  ##  #######    ##    ##
//   #####   ##      ####    ##   ##    ##    #####
//
//===========================================================

  void updateUsuario(int index) async {
    print('ENTRA A ACTUALIZAR');
    // _usuarioList[index].quantity = _usuarioList[index].quantity! + 1;
    // _usuarioList[index].isSynced = isDeviceConnected.value;
    // int id = await IsarHelper.instance.insertOne(_usuarioList[index]);
    // _usuarioList[index].id = id;
    // if (isDeviceConnected.value) {
    //   _cloudFirestoreHelper.updateMedicine(_usuarioList[index]);
    // }
    notifyListeners();
  }

//===========================================
//
//  #####    #####    ###    ####
//  ##  ##   ##      ## ##   ##  ##
//  #####    #####  ##   ##  ##  ##
//  ##  ##   ##     #######  ##  ##
//  ##   ##  #####  ##   ##  ####
//
//===========================================

  //get inventory list
  Future<void> getUsuarioList({bool showLoading = true}) async {
    print('ENTRA A OBTENER');
    showLoading ? startLoading() : null;
    _usuarioList = [];

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) async {
      if (isDeviceConnected.value) {
        // _inventoryList = await _cloudFirestoreHelper.getAllMedicine();

        IsarHelper.instance.insertFresh(_usuarioList);
      } else {
        _usuarioList = await IsarHelper.instance.getItems();
      }
    });

    stopLoading();
    notifyListeners();
  }

//=======================================================
//
//  ####    #####  ##      #####  ######  #####
//  ##  ##  ##     ##      ##       ##    ##
//  ##  ##  #####  ##      #####    ##    #####
//  ##  ##  ##     ##      ##       ##    ##
//  ####    #####  ######  #####    ##    #####
//
//=======================================================

  void removeUsuario(Usuario usuario) async {
    print('ENTRA A ELIMINAR');
    usuario.isSynced = false;
    await IsarHelper.instance.removeItem(usuario);
    // _usuarioList.removeWhere((element) => element.code_value == inventory.code_value);
    if (isDeviceConnected.value) {
      // _cloudFirestoreHelper.removeInventory(usuario);
    } else {
      deletedUsuarios.add(usuario);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

//=============================================
//
//   ####  ##    ##  ##     ##   ####
//  ##      ##  ##   ####   ##  ##
//   ###     ####    ##  ## ##  ##
//     ##     ##     ##    ###  ##
//  ####      ##     ##     ##   ####
//
//=============================================

  void checkIsSynced() async {
    print('ENTRA A VERIFICAR');
    List<Usuario> unsyncedUsuarios =
        await IsarHelper.instance.getUnsyncedData();
    if (deletedUsuarios.isNotEmpty) {
      for (Usuario element in deletedUsuarios) {
        // _cloudFirestoreHelper.removeInventory(element);
      }
      deletedUsuarios.clear();
    }
    if (unsyncedUsuarios.isNotEmpty) {
      for (Usuario element in unsyncedUsuarios) {
        element.isSynced = true;
        // await _cloudFirestoreHelper.updateMedicine(element);
        IsarHelper.instance.updateSync(element);
      }
    }
    getUsuarioList(showLoading: false);
  }
}
```